# How do I display a small browser-less website on my screen?

Tags: windows, software-rec, web

I am looking for a way to display some information I have on a web server (just some text) in a small window (always on top) at the top of the screen - kind of like a popup.

It should be just some small client that runs on Windows, basically doing the same as a browser just without all the extra stuff. Maybe there is already some program designed to do that. I would also build it myself, but then how?

I am open for any way to accomplish this.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell us which Windows OS...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like Google Chrome's `Wrench > Tools > Create application shourcuts...` to create a shortcut to the website in a window without the extra stuff (no toolbars, menus). This is also available in Firefox through the [Prism addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozilla-labs-prism/).

If a full sized website isn't what you want to show, try something like [Snippage](http://snippage.gabocorp.com) which allows you to highlight the actual region you want to display.

I'm not too sure if the latest version of Snippage has *Always On Top* action. Although on every setup I've had I've always installed an Always On Top tool like [Always On Top Maker](http://www.fadsoft.net/AlwaysOnTopMaker.htm)

Comment: Very nice. I think I´ll go with Prism ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Opera Widgets](http://widgets.opera.com/widgetize/) are the first thing that come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you running? Server 2008? You can install the desktop experience to get widgets and the sidebar.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/233bae03-4e9f-4dc6-89bc-0b729fbdf64a/

Answer (score 0):

Firefox and XUL, or acrobat AIR

XUL or AIR allows you to define your own window structure (menus, decorations). You can then define your own interface to the firefox gecko rendering engine. It is quite a lot of over kill if all you want to do is display a little greater message.

I might try using a start up script to launch IE, have a html file with some java script that will automatically close the IE when it opens after pushing a little pop window or window with no decorations. Java script could probably do all that. 
http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jwinopen.htm

window.open('url to open','window name','attribute1,attribute2');